# Scalar multiplication of adjoints and inverses

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse-function

Let's suppose for a matrix $A$, the adjoint is $adjA$, the determinant is $detA$ and the inverse is $A^{-1}$. If I am now considering a matric $kA$, what can I say about the relation between $A$ and $kA$, between $adj(A)$ and $adj(kA)$, between $det(A)$ and $det(kA)$, between $A^{-1}$ and $(kA)^{-1}$

---

If the answer depends on the order of the matrix, which I believe it should according to my preliminary analysis, consider only for $2\times2$ or $3\times3$ orders. Also, you can change the notation if you want to...

Comment: Yes, I know I didn't mention scalar multiplication of matrices and determinants in the title but I get confused between the differences  and since it will inevitably be used in the proof I thought I would include it too

Comment: $(kA)^{-1} = k^{-1} A^{-1}$ (can check directly from the definition).$\det(kA) = k^n \det A$ ([famous formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Immediate_consequences)). And $A\text{adj}(A) = \text{det}(A)$ so we deduce $\text{adj}(kA) = k^{n-1} \text{adj}(A)$.

Comment: @preferred_anon isnt it $A\text{adj}(A) = \text{det}(A)*I$ where I is the identity matrix?

Comment: yess, I deduced the last one too. I actually started in a different way which is maybe why I got it wrong maybe. I didn't know these as they weren't thought in my class. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Yes, that's right.